Collection View coming up empty and with mixed items
I have written the below code to show collections and products from a store. I have used multiple HList1 component and HList2 component on the screen. The issue is when I fast scroll down the Home screen which contains these HList components, some of them are coming up empty. Also, if I goto another screen and then come back to HList, the cell contents are refreshed, but I haven't added anything to refresh the screen.
Please help.
import UIKit

enum cellStyle {
    case Hlist1
    case Hlist2
}

class HList: UITableViewCell, UIComponentProtocol, UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
    var delegate: UIElementSelectedProtocol?
    var cellId = "HListCell1"
    var componentLayout: UIComponent?
    fileprivate var collections: PageableArray<CollectionModel>!
    fileprivate var products: PageableArray<ProductModel>!
    var HList2Type : CGSize?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var currentCellStyle: cellStyle = .Hlist1
    var productQuantity : Int = 1
    weak var parentViewController: UIViewController?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        contentView.backgroundColor = .background1
        
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        let nib1 = UINib(nibName: "HListCell1", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(nib1, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HListCell1")
        let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "HListCell2", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(nib2, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HListCell2")
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleCustomerLogin), name: Notification.Name("CustomerLoggedIn"), object: nil)

    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
    @objc func handleCustomerLogin() {
        updateUI(componentLayout!)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("CustomerLoggedIn"), object: nil)
    }
    
    func updateUI(_ layout: UIComponent) {
        componentLayout = layout
        
        fetchElementValues() { [weak self] elements in
            self?.currentCellStyle = layout.style.contains("HSTYLE2") ? .Hlist2 : .Hlist1
            self?.cellId = self?.currentCellStyle == .Hlist2 ? "HListCell2" : "HListCell1"
            
            let clnLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            clnLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: ThemeLayoutProvider.componetVerticalPadding, left: ThemeLayoutProvider.componetHorizontalPadding, bottom: ThemeLayoutProvider.componetVerticalPadding, right: ThemeLayoutProvider.componetHorizontalPadding)
            clnLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            clnLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            clnLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
            
            if self?.currentCellStyle == .Hlist2 {
                clnLayout.itemSize = ThemeLayoutProvider.hList2Size
            } else {
                
                switch self?.componentLayout?.elementType {
                case "products":
                    if AccountController.shared.AddToCartEnabled {
                        if AccountController.shared.customer != nil {
                            clnLayout.itemSize = ThemeLayoutProvider.hList1Size(for: .productAddToCart)
                        } else {
                            clnLayout.itemSize = ThemeLayoutProvider.hList1Size(for: .product)
                        }
                    } else {
                        clnLayout.itemSize = ThemeLayoutProvider.hList1Size(for: .product)
                    }
                case "collection" :
                    clnLayout.itemSize = ThemeLayoutProvider.hList1Size(for: .collection)
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            
            if let products = self?.products, products.items.count > 0 {
                let targetIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
                self?.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: targetIndexPath, at: .left, animated: false)
            }
            
            self?.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = clnLayout
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()

        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchElementValues(completion: @escaping ([Any]) -> Void) {
        switch componentLayout?.elementType {
        case "products":
            if let ids = componentLayout!.elements?.compactMap({ "gid://shopify/Product/"+($0.dataValue ?? "")}) {
                ShopifyClient.sharedInstance().fetchProducts(with: ids) {[weak self] prdcts in
                    self?.products = prdcts
                    completion(prdcts!.items)
                }
            }
        case "collection":
            if let ids = componentLayout!.elements?.compactMap({ "gid://shopify/Collection/"+($0.dataValue ?? "")}) {
                ShopifyClient.sharedInstance().fetchCollections(with: ids) {[weak self] colltns in
                    self?.collections = colltns
                    completion(colltns!.items)
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
}

extension HList: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch componentLayout?.elementType {
        case "products":
            return products?.items.count ?? 0
        case "collection":
            return collections?.items.count ?? 0
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : HListCell! = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)  as? HListCell
        cell.cellStyle = currentCellStyle
        cell.delegate = self
        if componentLayout!.style.contains("HSTYLE2") {
            cell.mainView.borderColor = .border
        }
        
        let anElement = componentLayout?.elements?[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.setImageFrom(URL.init(string: anElement?.imageUrl ?? ""), placeholder: .imagePlaceHolderSqure)
        
        switch currentCellStyle {
        case .Hlist1:
            if componentLayout?.elementType == "products" {
                cell.product = products?.items[indexPath.row]
                if let titleName = componentLayout?.elements?[indexPath.row] {
                    cell.nameLable.text = titleName.title
                }
                cell.circleView.isHidden = false
                cell.heartImageView.isHidden = false
                cell.subLabel.isHidden = false
                
                if AccountController.shared.AddToCartEnabled {//change in constraints}
else if componentLayout?.elementType == "collection" {
                cell.collection = collections.items[indexPath.row]
                if let titleName = componentLayout?.elements?[indexPath.row] {
                    cell.nameLable.text = titleName.title
                }
                cell.circleView.isHidden = true
                cell.heartImageView.isHidden = true
                cell.subLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.addToCart.isHidden = true
                cell.productDescription.isHidden = true
                cell.nameLable.isHidden = false
                cell.nameLable.numberOfLines = 2
                
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    cell.nameLable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.imageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
                    cell.addToCart.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0),
                    cell.nameLable.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31),
                    cell.productDescription.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0),
                    cell.subLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
                ])
            }
case .Hlist2:
            if componentLayout?.elementType == "products" {
                cell.product = products?.items[indexPath.row]
                if let titleName = componentLayout?.elements?[indexPath.row] {
                    cell.nameLable.text = titleName.title
                }
                cell.circleView.isHidden = false
                cell.heartImageView.isHidden = false
                cell.subLabel.isHidden = false
                                if AccountController.shared.AddToCartEnabled {
// change in constraints
}
else if componentLayout?.elementType == "collection" {
                cell.collection = collections.items[indexPath.row]
                if let titleName = componentLayout?.elements?[indexPath.row] {
                    cell.nameLable.text = titleName.title
                }
                cell.circleView.isHidden = true
                cell.heartImageView.isHidden = true
                cell.subLabel.isHidden = true
                cell.productDescription.isHidden = true
                cell.addToCart.isHidden = true
                cell.productNameTop.constant = 30
                cell.nameLable.numberOfLines = 2
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

extension HList : DismissVariantView {
    func didDismissToCart() {}
    
    func didDimissToCheckout(item: [CartItem]) {}
    
    func didDismissToProductDetail() {}
    
    func didDismissToProductList(product: ProductModel, selectedVariant: VariantModel) {
        if let indexPath = indexPath(for: product) {
            // Reload the cell at the indexPath
                        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            
            // Check if the product is in the cart
            if CartController.shared.cartContainsProduct(product) {
                // Update the "Add to Cart" button title
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? HListCell {
                    cell.addToCart.setTitle("Go To Cart", for: .normal)
                    cell.isVariantInCart = true
                }
            } else {
                // Update the "Add to Cart" button title
                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? HListCell {
                    cell.addToCart.setTitle("Add to Cart", for: .normal)
                    cell.isVariantInCart = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


extension HList {
    func indexPath(for product: ProductModel) -> IndexPath? {
        guard let products = products else { return nil }
        if let index = products.items.firstIndex(of: product) {
            return IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        }
        return nil
    }
}

I've been trying to figure out what is causing the issue and saw some solutions that it associated with the dequeuing of the cell, so I have set the name, image etc to nil but that doesnt seem to work.

About the refresh issue i suggest you double check your class HList presenting code you may creating an instance for every call (push, present) that make your vc initialize from the scratch

About some empty cells during fast scroll i can suggest you to check your cell prepareForReuse function
